# What's the difference between BaseAdapter and ArrayAdapter?

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I want to know the difference between using `BaseAdapter` and `ArrayAdapter`.

I have been achieving what I want through `ArrayAdapters`.

Does it affect the performance of the `ListView` on the adapter interface in which it is implemented ?

And, the last question is, can i achieve anything doing with `ListView` using any of these `Adapters`, or, there are certain cases where specific adapter only can be used?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html. ArrayAdpter. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html. BaseAdapter. ArrayAdapter is a concrete sub class of BaseAdapter

Comment: Simply ArrayAdapter is already constructed, we just need to use it. but the BaseAdapter is more generic adapter for which we need to provide implementation .(getView(),getcount() etc methods in Adapter)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Here is the difference:

- `BaseAdapter` is a very generic adapter that allows you to do pretty much whatever you want. However, you have to do a bit more coding yourself to get it working.
- `ArrayAdapter` is a more complete implementation that works well for data in arrays or `ArrayList`s. Similarly, there is a related `CursorAdapter` that you should use if your data is in a `Cursor`. Both of these extend `BaseAdapter`.

If your data is in a specialized collection of some sort or if you don't want the default behavior that `ArrayAdapter` provides, you will likely want to extend `BaseAdapter` to get the flexibility you need.

The performance of each really depends on how you implement them or change their behavior. At their core, either one can be just as effective (especially considering that an `ArrayAdapter` *is* a `BaseAdapter`).

You can do pretty much whatever you want with any adapter, but keep in mind that `BaseAdapter` is abstract, so you can't use it directly.

Comment: The default behavior that `ArrayAdapter` provides (as mentioned by @tanis-7x ) is that there can be only 1 `TextView` inside the list item, actually very limited behavior. If there are multiple controls in each list item, you must use `BaseAdapter` and to the job by yourself. Of course you can still use `ArrayAdapter`, because `ArrayAdapter` is a `BaseAdapter`.

Answer (score 22):

`BaseAdapter` is abstract while `ArrayAdapter` extends `BaseAdapter` (it is a concrete implementation of a `BaseAdapter`). If you extends for `ArrayAdapter` you are inheriting all the  `ArrayAdapter`'s features and, override its implementation you can modify the `ArrayAdapter` behavior. If you extends   `BaseAdapter` you must implements all the Abstract methods, that ArrayAdapter already implements.

> Also, does it affects the performance of the ListView

no it does not.

> And, the last question is, can i achieve anything doing with ListView
>   using any of these Adapters, or, there are certain cases where
>   specific adapter only can be used ?

If the implementation in the SDK fulfill your needs why you need to override it and re-invent the wheel?

The main difference between them is that `BaseAdapter`  can not be instantiate while `ArrayAdapter` can

Answer (score 9):

In response to your 3 questions:

(1) [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html), according to the Android docs, is just a superclass of a number of adapter types, one of which is `ArrayAdapter`. There are a number of other adapters that are derived from `BaseAdapter` that fit different purposes. As a result it is unlikley there is any difference in efficiency between the two; you just get access to a different set of functions/methods with the various subclasses.

(2) The efficiency of your `ArrayAdapter` depends on the efficiency of what you're doing inside that class, i.e. the processing of bitmaps and other data.

(3) You could probably figure out a way to work your `ListView` using a different kind of adapter, however, the reason `ArrayAdapter` works is because it usually makes sense given the goal is to build an interactive list. The `ArrayAdapte` takes an `Array`, usually an `ArrayList` of objects, that it then processes to create the backing information for the `ListView`. In that sense the set up of `ArrayList` --> `ArrayAdapter` --> `ListView` just logically makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

One more difference between BaseAdapter and ArrayAdapters is, if you extend array adapter you have to call super class constructor in the subclass constructor.

```
UserListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

   List<String> UserList;
   Context context;

   public UserListAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<String> listUsers) {
     super(context, resource, listUsers);      /* Super class constructor is called */
     UserList = listUsers;
     this.context = context;
   }

}
```

But there is no super class for BaseAdapter.  As BaseAdapter serves as super class for all other adapters

```
UserListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

   List<String> UserList;
   Context context;

   public UserListAdapter(Context context, int resource,List<String> listUsers) {
     /* No super class constructor */
     UserList = listUsers;
     this.context = context;
   }

}
```

Comment: And no need on DataType Specified in BaseAdapter like in ArrayAdapter.
Example : ArrayAdapter<String>

Comment: also you should never use `List<T> UserList;` in the class which extends  `ArrayAdapter<T>`

Answer (score 6):

```
private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[]{
            "Afghanistan", "Angola", "Australia", "Bangladesh", "Belgium",
            "Bhutan", "Brazil", "Canada", "China", "Denmark"
    };

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here we can't use BaseAdapter like ArrayAdapter.

Answer (score 3):

`BaseAdapter`s are more minimal and customizable. `ArrayAdapter`s implement the most general uses of `ListAdapter`s, but sometimes they are not enough.

However, almost everything can be achieved by the use of `ArrayAdapter`s. If your lists are already working by using ArrayAdapter correctly, you have nothing to gain from BaseAdapter.

However, if you are storing your `Context`, `Arrays` or `Lists` in your ArrayAdapter implementation, maybe you'll want to switch to `BaseAdapter`, as `ArrayAdapter` already has them implemented.

Anyway, if you're doing that, you can always remove those items, and resort to using `getItem()` to get the Array items, `getCount()` to get the size of the array, and `getContext()` to inflate your views.