# how to add customised layout to Arrayadapter?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to create a `ListView` with customized layout. each item in the `listView` should look like as shown in the `item.xml` posted below.

in the code, i used

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<T>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listi_tems_layout, topicsList);
```

but it is not working because the constructor of the `ArrayAdapter<T>` accepts the second parameter as `int` something like

`android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

, and in my case it is customized layout which is

```
R.layout.listi_tems_layout
```

which adapter should i use or how to solve this. thanks

**Item**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/tvlist_topic"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/ivList_delete"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/delete_icon"
    android:contentDescription="icon to delete item from the Listview"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
<CheckBox 
    android:id="@+id/cbList_hook"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="false"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

**mainlayout**:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >
....
....
....

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/lvEco_topics"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="470dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/tvEco_topic"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:divider="@android:drawable/alert_light_frame"></ListView>
<Button 
    android:id="@+id/btEco_save"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/lvEco_topics"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Save"/>
```

**code**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ArrayList<String> topicsList;
private ListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

    topicsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    topicsList.add("topic1");
    topicsList.add("topic2");
    topicsList.add("topic3");
    topicsList.add("topic4");
    topicsList.add("topic5");
    topicsList.add("topic6");

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<T>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listi_tems_layout, topicsList);
```

Comment: what problem getting using `adapter = new ArrayAdapter<T>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listi_tems_layout, topicsList);` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK the problem i am getting is 2 the constructor is undefined"

Comment: @MD i tried your suggestion, but i receive a warnin says 2Type safety: The constructor ArrayAdapter(Context, int, List) belongs to the raw type ArrayAdapter. References to generic type ArrayAdapter<T> should be parameterized"

Comment: create adapter as `ArrayAdapter<String>  adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listi_tems_layout, topicsList);` and see my  answer for other changes

Answer (score 8):

> ArrayAdapter accepts the second parameter as int something like
>   android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1

When not customizing `getView` method of `ArrayAdapter` then custom layout require one TextView with `android:id="@android:id/text1"` id and show value in one TextView.

To run application with current code add `android:id="@android:id/text1"` for `TextView` in  `R.layout.listi_tems_layout` layout.

Because `R.layout.listi_tems_layout` layout contains other views also with TextView so create custom Adapter by extending ArrayAdapter class to access other views also.

See following example:[Custom ArrayAdapter for a ListView (Android)](https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/)

Comment: ok but now by extending "ArrayAdapter", i need to specify te the paramter "T", ArrayAdapter<T>, what value should it be?

Comment: @rmaik : use `extends ArrayAdapter<String>`

Comment: is it because the Arraylist i have consists of Strings?

Comment: Actually, the id can be anything you want. The only requirement for the custom layout is to have only a TextView inside of it.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure if it's still relevant,
from the source ArrayAdapter seem to have constructor that accept textview resource in 3rd parameter, not sure if it's juts newly added in 2017 :D,

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,YourCustomLayoutID,TextViewIDinYourLayout,ListData);
```

and from the source, if you didn't supply textview layout id, it will assume that the whole view is a textview, so I think it's possible to use custom view without extending/creating new adapter (I know, I hate to create one myself), but you need to provide textview used for the text

Answer (score 4):

create a class and extends with base adapter like this and then set this adapter

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.test.R;
import com.itoks.model.ClientDetails;

public class ClientListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    // ArrayList<String> name, company, email, id, status;
    ArrayList<ClientDetails> clientArrayList;
    Context c;

    public ClientListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ClientDetails> list) {
        clientArrayList = list;
        this.c = c;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return clientArrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return clientArrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View row = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) c
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item_clients, parent,
                    false);
        } else {
            row = convertView;
        }
        ClientDetails detail = clientArrayList.get(position);
        TextView name = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvClientFullName);
        name.setText(detail.name);
        TextView email = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvClientEmail);
        email.setText(detail.email);
        TextView id = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvClientID);
        id.setText("ID : " + detail.id);
        TextView company = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.tvClientCompanyName);
        company.setText(detail.company);
        TextView status = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tvClientStatus);
        status.setText("Status:" + detail.status);
        return row;
    }

}
```

Comment: getItem returns null ??

Comment: No matter you can access that item with your customized ArrayList with the position.

Comment: Still a bad practice.

Comment: return clientArrayList.get(position); of course ... You should also protect against null list in constructor

Comment: But in this project I didn't need to access that item directly. Thats why I am returning null here.

Comment: If another dev uses that adapter, he has no way to know you didn't implement that method. If you really don't want to implement it correctly, the correct way would be throwing NotImplementedException to inform user of that class that the method is not implemented. I also recommend you read this answer about BaseAdapter vs ArrayAdapter, since you seem to worry about having to implement too many methods : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16796355/1178337

Comment: for live example kindly go through **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMSdD05NVYQ**

Answer (score 2):

As I understand you. You are trying to have custom layout in ArrayAdapter. It's not possible. Yout need to write your own custom adapter extending arrayAdapter class where you define how to deal with your custom layout using your topicsList. Something like this:

```
public class ChatUserAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserChat> {

private Activity context;
private List<UserChat> userList;
private int ilayout;

public ChatUserAdapter(Activity context, int layout, List<UserChat> userList) {
    super(context, layout, userList);
    this.context = context;
    this.userList = userList;
    this.ilayout = layout;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvEmail;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    View rowView = convertView;
    if (rowView == null) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(ilayout, null, true);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvEmail = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.tv_email);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
    }

    UserChat item = userList.get(position);
    viewHolder.tvEmail.setText(item.getName() + " " + item.getSurname());
    return rowView;
}
}
```

Comment: for live example kindly go through **https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMSdD05NVYQ**

Comment: Passing Activity to adapter is a bad idea, as adapter can leak whole activity.

Answer (score -1):

Please create your own ItemAdapter which extends ArrayAdapter<>.

```
public class ItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
private int resource;
private List<Item> items;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
    this.resource = resource;
    this.items = items;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LinearLayout itemView;
    final Item item = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        itemView = new LinearLayout(getContext());

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        layoutInflater.inflate(resource, itemView, true);
    }
    else {
        itemView = (LinearLayout) convertView;
    }
```

And load your item.xml in MainActivity onCreate()

```
public class MainActivity{
    private List<Item> items;
    private ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
    @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.item, items);
```